# Getting exception on downloading an XML file

Tags: android, xml, web-services, download

I am developing an Android App and in that i am trying to download XML file from this URL `http://data.gov.in/sites/default/files/Date-Wise-Prices-all-Commodity.xml` and trying to save this file into my sd card.

I want to download file when button is clicked. So, I use following code on my Button Click..

```
try
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://data.gov.in/sites/default/files/Date-Wise-Prices-all-Commodity.xml");

        //create the new connection

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        //set up some things on the connection

        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        //and connect!

        urlConnection.connect();

        //set the path where we want to save the file

        //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the

        //sd card.

        File SDCardRoot = new File("/sdcard/"+"XML_folder/");

        //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename

        //which we want to save the file as.

        File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"webservice.xml");

        //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created

        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

        //this will be used in reading the data from the internet

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        //this is the total size of the file

        int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

        //variable to store total downloaded bytes

        int downloadedSize = 0;

        //create a buffer...

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

        //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file

        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) 

        {

        //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card

        fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

        //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded

        downloadedSize += bufferLength;

        int progress=(int)(downloadedSize*100/totalSize);

        //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe

        //updateProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);

        }

        //close the output stream when done

        fileOutput.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

As I have used `try and catch` its catching an Exception and showing me this message `data.gov.in` `(java.net.UnknownHostException: data.gov.in)`

So, what to do now?

Comment: I want to download XML file its kinda web services...so if there is any thing wrong please let me know..

Comment: "The page you requested is not available."

Comment: @H.Moody: I have provided the link from where I want to download and its also opening in my browser. So, please tell me exactly where's the problem ?

Comment: did u add the INTERNET Permission in your manifest file

Comment: @Droid: yeah now i have added the permission but now getting this exception `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/XML_folder/webservice.xml (No such file or directory)` help ?

Comment: is there any folder named XML_FOLDER in your sdcard

Comment: great.. i am also sending the same code you edited.. nice work :)

Comment: @Droid:  can u please help me in how to use this XML file data in my app ?`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39473/discussion-between-shiv-and-droid)

Answer (score 1):

Check your manifest file,permission given or not and also use AsyncTask or thread concept for url connection(background work).

```
         ibut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
       public void onClick(View v) 
          {
            new Thread(new Runnable() 
                {
                  public void run() 
                    {
                try
                 {
                     //http connection code. 
                 }      
                          catch(Exception e) 
                         {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                         }

                }).start();


        }});
```

Comment: Can you please explain me your concept. Actually i am new in Android development. So, it'll be a favor for me.

Comment: @Shiv where you run your app in device or emulator?.can you pls post your manifest file?

Comment: hey as you told I have added the permission for using Internet `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` but now i am getting this `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/XML_folder/webservice.xml (No such file or directory)` help ??

Comment: I run my app in device

Comment: @Shiv File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/sdcard/XML_folder");
           if (!root.exists()) {
               root.mkdirs();
           }
          File gpxfile = new File(root, "webservice.xml");

Answer (score 1):

This error is coming while

1. `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` if you forgot to write this
2. if your internet is very slow or not working
3. and last if your server is not responding your request for any reason.

Comment: my this problem is solved. now can u please help me in `how to use this XML file data` in my app ?`

Answer (score 0):

put permission into manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

try this code for file not found

```
//set the path where we want to save the file

    //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the

    //sd card.

    File SDCardRoot = new File("/sdcard/"+"XML_folder/");

    if(SDCardRoot.exists() == false){
         SDCardRoot.mkdirs();  
    }

    //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename

    //which we want to save the file as.

    File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"webservice.xml");
```

Comment: how can I forget this..btw thanks..but now i am getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sdcard/XML_folder/webservice.xml (No such file or directory)`

Comment: xml is not getting downloading into this /sdcard/XML_folder/webservice.xml place check.!!

Comment: Do I have to create this location ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
URL url = new URL(Your URL);

                //create the new connection

                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                //set up some things on the connection

                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                //and connect!

                urlConnection.connect();

                //set the path where we want to save the file

                //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the

                //sd card.

                File SDCardRoot = new File("/sdcard/");

                //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename

                //which we want to save the file as.

                File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"hello.xml");

                //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created

                FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

                //this will be used in reading the data from the internet

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                //this is the total size of the file

                int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

                //variable to store total downloaded bytes

                int downloadedSize = 0;

                //create a buffer...

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

                //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file

                while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) 

                {

                //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card

                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

                //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded

                downloadedSize += bufferLength;

                int progress=(int)(downloadedSize*100/totalSize);

                //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe

                //updateProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);

                }

                //close the output stream when done

                fileOutput.close();
```